# Comparing two lists by specific criteria and updating/inserting records for the matched criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, transactions

I have written a code/database design where I have following classes mapped in my application:

```
public class Items 
{
public int ItemsId {get;set;} // suppose this is the PK in my table
public string ItemId { get; set; } // this is not same as table PK
public string Title  { get; set; }
public int QuantitySoldTotal { get; set; } 
public List<Transactions> transactions { get; set; }
}
```

And Transactions class:

```
public class Transactions 
{
public string TransactionID { get; set; }
public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
public int SaleQuantity { get; set; }
public int ItemsId {get;set;} // lets imagine this is the FK in my table Transactions
}
```

So now I have a situation where I have the old items and their transactions in my DB like following:

```
var oldItemsAndTransactions = new List<Items>(); // suppose this is from DB and it has 5000 items, and each of these items contains a collection of transactions...
```

And now I have a new list like this:

```
var newItemsAndTransactions = new List<Items>(); 
// This is already filtered list where contents of this list are only items that have different QuantitySoldTotal property and
```

Now here is the part where I get confused and I don't know what to do next:

- I would like to update those items which have different QuantitySoldTotal property in my Items table and add the difference of transactions ( meaning to add only new transactions). New transactions are those which have different TransactionID parameter in table.
- And items which are not present in the Items table at all (meaning their ItemID string - not PK, isn't there , I'd like to insert all of them and their corresponding transactions)...

I'm thinking this could be done via IEqualityComparer , but I'm not really sure how to do it exactly? Can someone help me out ?

P.S. This isn't the same case as now I'm dealing with comparing with list of lists, and i'd like to do this in a efficient and fast manner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing IEqualityComparer in C# .NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596909/implementing-iequalitycomparer-in-c-sharp-net-mvc)

Comment: @TeodorKurtev Yes that's the question asked by me but... It's not really the same as now I'm dealing with List of Lists (comparing list of lists)... ?

Comment: Have you tried the LINQ approach? The logic should be very similar - the `Where` and `Any` methods can help you filter your collections (doesn't matter if you have list of list). Given that, the `IEqualityComparer ` can also work, you will just have more code.

Comment: @TeodorKurtev yes but I'm worried about the performance with LINQ, will it be able to handle large collections, large inserts of data of mising items ?

Comment: _but I'm worried about the performance with LINQ_? As opposed to what? You still need to iterate through your collection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Like the fact let's say that items collection contains 15000 items inside, which it will at some point, there are some collections with 200k items inside, I think inserting them through LINQ Add & SaveChanges() or AddRange wouldn't be the smartest idea ,no ?

Comment: You can't 'insert' items _though LINQ_ (LINQ is for querying data, not updating it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes good point, what would you suggest me todo as best solution for this case ?

Comment: And are you saying that there are 15000 `Items` and each `Item` can contain 200K `Transactions`?

Comment: Wait so we are talking about this in the context of EntityFramework? I'm a bit confused. If you are worrying about large inserts, you can always use BulkInsert [http://entityframework-extensions.net/](http://entityframework-extensions.net/) or any other NuGet package that supports the idea.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes correct :D ... that's my nightmare xD Well not 200k transactions but lets say 1000 transactions each

Comment: @TeodorKurtev Yes , but when I insert with bulk insert I don't get the PK value of the inserted record back in code :D...

Comment: @StephenMuecke 200k items (collection of 200k) and each of these 200k to contain 1000 transactions each

Comment: Whether you query your data making use of a LINQ `.Except()` or `.Intersect()` etc with an `IEqualityComparer` or use a LINQ .Where()` etc is unlikely to make any significant difference (you have not shown your code so not sure what you have tried). It's the amount of records that you need to iterate which will impact the performance. DO they all need to be updated at once? Can you offload it to a separate scheduled service?

Comment: @StephenMuecke good point with the separate scheduled service... They don't have to be updated all at once, it can be done in batches ?